# If it were 'there', could subject-auxiliary inversion still possible?

Tags: inversion

> At three-thirty that afternoon, Harry, Ron, and the other Gryffindors
>   hurried down the front steps onto the grounds for their first flying
>   lesson. It was a clear, breezy day, and the grass rippled under their
>   feet as they marched down the sloping lawns toward a smooth, flat lawn
>   on the opposite side of the grounds to the forbidden forest, whose
>   trees were swaying darkly in the distance.
>
> The Slytherins were already there, and **so were twenty broomsticks
>   lying** in neat lines on the ground. Harry had heard Fred and George
>   Weasley complain about the school brooms, saying that some of them
>   started to vibrate if you flew too high, or always flew slightly to
>   the left.
>
> ––– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

There’s subject-auxiliary inversion by the pronoun for locative complement, *so*. (1) In here, is *so* re-placing *already there*? (2) If the previous locative complement were *there* not *already there*, still could the inversion be proper (The Slytherins were ***there***, and ***so*** were~) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introductory element *so* is an obligatory trigger for subject-auxiliary inversion (abbreviated as SAI):

> 1. ..., and so [were]<sub>AUX</sub> [ twenty broomsticks lying in neat lines on the ground ]<sub>SUBJ</sub>.
> 2. *..., and so [ twenty broomsticks lying in neat lines on the ground ]<sub>SUBJ</sub> [were]<sub>AUX</sub> .

Example 2 is ungrammatical regardless of whether *already* is in the preceding clause.  Removing it doesn't change whether it exhibits SAI.